# How to find indexes of the most small duplicated value in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, indexing, duplicates, listbox, minimum

I tried everything i could find online and spent a lot of time on this but I cant do it.

It's a form with a `ListBox` with random numbers from 20 to 30 and I need to find the min and show its position. The hard part is that if i have 2 of the same number or 3 of them, then I don't know what to do and I tried almost everything.

This is the code i did so far:

```
Random r = new Random();

int[] a;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    a = new int[10];
   
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a[i] = r.Next(20, 31);
        listBox1.Items.Add(a[i]);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    int[] b;
    b = new int[10];
    int mini=3435, i,index=0;
    b = (int[])a.Clone();
   
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] < mini)
        {
            mini = b[i];
        }
    }
    
    index = Array.IndexOf(b, mini);
    label2.Text = Convert.ToString("la pozitia: " + index);
    

    label1.Text = Convert.ToString("Minimul este: " +mini );
   
}
```

This is how it should look:
[image: This is how it should look]

Comment: *"The hard part is that if i have 2 of the same number or 3 of them, then i dont know what to do"* that business logic. I.e. there is no general rule how to do it. It depends on your business case. What would you like to do if there are multiple matches?

Comment: You could add a frequency column

Comment: Are you allowed to use Linq?

Comment: Im not allowed to use Linq , JHBonarius

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)` is bad. First: this is not C, so you can declare objects where you use them (and even in C you would write `for (int i=0; ...)`. Next, in C# and similar languages indices are zero-based. I.e. `for (int i=0; i < b.Length; i++)`. (Or you can set `int mini=b[0];`, which will also work)

Comment: @JHBonarius i think i can use that, since i also have and `a.Clone()` in my code

Comment: I was no the one saying that. `Clone` is part of `Array`. `Min` is part of Linq.

Comment: @JHBonarius our teachers  like us to do the exercices this way. I agree its not the best option, but its the only way they accept our work.

Comment: @JHBonarius ah i didnt know that one. Then i cant use anything from Linq.

Comment: First find the minimum value by looping the array (you don't have to clone it). Then find all the indices in the array that have that value (by looping through the list again) and `Add` their index to a new `List`. Voila: that list contains all the indices (you can `string.Join` them with a comma separator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you simply want to output the positions as a comma seperate list, you can use a separate string for the list of positions that match:

```
int[] b;
b = new int[10];
int mini = int.MaxValue, i, index = 0;
string miniList = "";
b = (int[])a.Clone();

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (b[i] < mini)
    {
        mini = b[i];
        miniList = "";
    }
    if (b[i] == mini)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(miniList))
        {
            miniList += ", ";
        }
        miniList += i;
    }
}

label1.Text = Convert.ToString("Minimul este: " + mini);
label2.Text = Convert.ToString("la pozitia: " + miniList);
```

NOTE: I also set the mini value to int.MaxValue to begin with so code should work with any number range

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much! You saved at least 4 more hours of my life

Comment: Cloning a to b is useless and a can be directly used, isn't it?

Comment: I wonder if the op actually learned anything  ps the new b[10] or even a.clone don't add much. You can just use a.

Comment: @Oliver Rogier i think it can be directly used but thats how our teacher wanted us to do it.